# How to generate a file in travis-ci?

Tags: yaml, travis-ci

I need to generate a file based on environment variables in a Travis-CI script.

For example, in my .travis.yml, I have:

```
before_script:
  - |
    cat > Config.xcconfig <<END
    API_URL = https://test.api.project.com
    END
script:
  # For example
  - cat Config.xcconfig
```

However, this generate the file with unwanted indent and with the `END`:

```
> cat Config.xcconfig
  API_URL = https://test.api.project.com
  END
```

I know I can use openssl to decrypt file in the repo, however I would prefer to not commit encrypted files to the repository. Any idea?

Comment: I saw you added the tag yaml @melpomene, but the generated JSON file in travis-ci shows "cat > Config.xcconfig << END\nAPI_URL = https://test.api.projet.com\nEND\n", which is correct.